# passing data from (grand) parent to parent to child to (grand) child and back up to (Grand) parent activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a grand parent activity called Department

```
    public class Department extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_department);
     .........
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeptDetail.class);

                    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
                    extra.putString("Department", getAdapterPosition()+"");
                    intent.putExtras(extra);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
     }
  }
```

Sends data about Department position to DepartmentDeatail activity

```
 public class DeptDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dept_detail);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    deptpos =  Integer.parseInt(extra.getString("Department"));
    .........
     public void onClick(View v) {
        int id= v.getId();
        Intent in; 
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        in = new Intent(DeptDetail.this, Mission.class);
        extras.putString("Mission",mission[deptpos]);
        extras.putString("Deptid", deptpos+"");
        in.putExtras(extras);
        startActivityForResult(in,1);
    }
}
```

and DeptDetail activity sends same Deptpos to its child activity Mission

```
public class Mission extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mission);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String mission = extra.getString("Mission");
    deptid=Integer.parseInt(extra.getString("Deptid"));

    TextView txtmission = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmission);
    try {
        txtmission.setText(mission);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        txtmission.setText("");
    }
}
}
```

And now I want same Deptid to be accessed in DeptDetail activity which always calls for intent from Department activity, which is not available as usual..
So please show me the way to pass the data to child and back to parent.

I tried

```
onActivityResult(..)
```

but it wasn't called before onCreate where extra is read and generating NullPointerException

Comment: Continue with `onActivityResult` just describe where exactly it is causing problem ??

Comment: when child returns to parent onCreate is called in DepDetail and the statement extra.getString(...) causes nullPointerException. As it was supposed to get data from parent.

Comment: add an if condition before `extra.getString(...) ` this line stating `if(extra!=null){ extra.getString(...) }`..!!

Comment: is onActivityResult is called after onCreate?? what if I want to set same values passed to/from child activity as a label on toolbar.

Comment: `onActivityResult` will be immediately call after `onCreate`. We can say in fraction of milliseconds you can set label in `onActivityResult` **that will work without any delay**..!!

Comment: but when i press backbutton it generates result but when upbutton pressed on AppBar it doesn't create the resultForActivity.

Comment: what do you mean by up button?

Comment: <- in toolbar ,, I have setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(True) is set.. so pressing back button at the bottom of the screen calls onBackPressed() but pressing <- button on toolbar doen't call onBackPressed()

Comment: you will have your own implementation for `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(True)` can i see that implementation ?? whole activity ??

Comment: thank you very much for the reply;  got that working by implementing following code :                           @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Deptid", deptid+"");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }